# How I can change the path

Tags: javascript

I need change the path , I want save the file in C:\NEW\archivo.txt
I have used ActiveXObject  but this add-on doesn't work in Chrome..

```
  function saveTextAsFile()
    {      
        var textToWrite = document.getElementById("json_polyline").value;

        var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
        var fileNameToSaveAs =  "archivo.txt";

        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

        downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;

        downloadLink.innerHTML = "My Hidden Link";

        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);

        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

        downloadLink.click();
    }

    function destroyClickedElement(event)
    {
        document.body.removeChild(event.target);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking -- perhaps you can provide some more context, or an example showing what you're looking for? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks!

Comment: Is this code on/in a web page, that runs in the user's browser? If so, you can not choose where to save the file — only the user can make that choice. Allowing you, the web site author, to choose where to save a file and what to name the file would be a **massive** security hole.

Comment: Thank you for your coments...  The code its ok.. The information of the textarea is saved in a file txt .. when I download the archivo ..downloading the file is in automatic, always is in user/download.. I want change the site the download.. for example the new path  is in C:/*.TXT

Comment: Stephen , I understand your point about of security hole... but
the idea is : the client entered information in the textarea,
after press button the information is saved in file , the client don't  see the file ; after, the client search the file through the page html and it can upload the information..
the client never download the file